# Javafx parse the Textfield value into an integer

Tags: javafx-8

i am currently learning javafx i want to parse the value of a textfield into an integer this is the code i have . but it gives me error "Exception in Application start method " , is there any new syntax for parsing a textfield value into integer?

```
TextField TextaddPrice = new TextField();   
TextField TextaddQuantity= new TextField();        

int parsePrice = Integer.parseInt(TextaddPrice.getText());
int parseQuantity = Integer.parseInt(TextaddQuantity.getText());

int total = parsePrice * parseQuantity;
```

Comment: Can you add the complete stacktrace?

Comment: " Exception in Application start method " this is only error i got in my console .

Comment: Can you add the complete code?

Comment: ok haha the code is too long .

Comment: Then care to create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with least minimum code which explains the problem.

Comment: use a StringConverter instead of manual parsing. Unrelated: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: I keep forgetting: as of 8u40, there's a TextFormatter that can be applied to a TextField - should do all the conversions you'll need